# How to find what is your orbit given velocity at a point and altitude?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, orbital-motion

So I am learning orbital mechanics by myself and have recently found the formulae for R and vis-a-vis equation. Now I want to know is there way to find the apogee and perigee of the orbit I am if I just know the velocity of my vehicle and the altitude? Like is there a relationship I can derive and if yes then how? And if no what more do I need to calculate my orbit parameters?

Comment: Did you mean the [vis-viva equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vis-viva_equation)?

Comment: Also, could you edit the equation to elaborate on what you tried to find this relationship yourself? That way the answerers won't have to repeat things that you've already checked.